# Why does function not change original variable?

Tags: c++

How come when I run the following code it outputs 3 not 5? I was under the impression that passing a pointer to a function changes the original variable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void addTwo(int* b){
    b +=2;
}

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int* ptr = &a;
    addTwo(ptr);
    cout<<*ptr<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're adding to the pointer, not the value it points to. I think this is undefined behavior? Maybe?

Comment: "I think this is undefined behavior? "  Nope, it's just pointless.

Comment: It's also not _actually_ adding to the pointer (`int* ptr`), just a copy of it unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @CollinD Oh right, that makes sense.

Comment: IIRC just offsetting the pointer into an invalid address is formally UB. `+1` would have been fine, `+2` is out-of-bounds.

Comment: What Quentin said. 5.7/4: "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."  (And 5.3.1/3 "For purposes of pointer arithmetic and comparison, an object that is not an array element whose address is taken in this way is considered to belong to an array with one element of type `T`.")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add two, to the *contents* of what b points at.  What you are doing is incrementing the pointer.  You need to increment *b:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void addTwo(int* b){
    *b +=2;
}

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int* ptr = &a;
    addTwo(ptr);
    cout<<*ptr<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, so what was my code doing before exactly? What does incrementing the pointer mean and what does it result in?

Comment: Memory is stored consecutively.  Increasing b by one, points to the next memory location.  Increasing by 2 (as you did), points to the next one after that.  So if you had `int arr[] = { 5,6,7,8 }; addTwo(arr);printf("%d %d\n",arr[0],arr[2]);` you would see the output `5 9`. It would increment the memory element 2 after the start of the array.

Comment: @Adam Basically, a pointer is a variable that stores a memory address; the stored address indicates what it points to.  Pointer arithmetic modifies this stored address itself, instead of the data at the address.  Incrementing any pointer `T*`, in particular, changes the address so that it points to the next T in sequence, as if the pointer was actually a decayed array (mechanically, the address is increased by `sizeof(T)` bytes).

Comment: Similarly, adding 2 to a pointer actually adds `sizeof(T) * 2` to the actual address; with 4-byte `int`s, for example, `b += 2;` actually moves `b` forwards by 8 bytes, to move it forward by 2 `int`s.  (It's not as complex as it sounds, it works like indexing an array.  For any pointer `p`, `*(p + 2)` is exactly the same as `p[2]`, because `p[2]` is actually just nicer syntax for `*(p + 2)` when working with raw pointers.)

Comment: Also, your `addTwo()` doesn't actually modify `ptr` itself.  Since the pointer is passed by value, `addTwo()` has a local copy (`b`), and modifications to local copy `b` aren't reflected in actual pointer `ptr`.

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddb4291e80b4633c) should hopefully clarify things a bit.  \[Also, note that you shouldn't actually do this unless you really know what you're doing.  As [Quentin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708839/why-does-function-not-change-original-variable#comment74461762_43708839) and [aschepler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708839/why-does-function-not-change-original-variable#comment74461870_43708839) commented, pointer arithmetic can cause undefined behaviour if you do it wrong.]

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void addTwo(int& b){
    b +=2;
}

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    addTwo(a);
    cout<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

First thing, you should use references in C++ instead of pointers. It really is easier in the long run.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void addTwo(int* b){
    *b +=2;
}

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int* ptr = &a;
    addTwo(ptr);
    cout<<*ptr<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Second thing, you simply forgot the * in addTwo(), incrementing the pointer adress and not the content itself.